# assert_no_template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I was wondering if do we have something like `assert_no_template` as the opposite of the `assert_template`.

What I'm trying to test is that a concrete template is not used in the actual render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put this in my `test_helper.rb`:

```
  def assert_template_not_used(template, msg = nil)
    assert !@templates.any? {|t, num| t.match(template)}, msg
  end
```

Answer (score 12):

A better way would be to use the :count argument to assert_template:

```
assert_template :partial => 'YOUR_PARTIAL', :count => 0
```

Comment: cool!, I think this can make a very good combination with the @RachelShallit answer.

Comment: Very cool. I used this to assert a multi-part form would and wouldn't render parts until it was ready. Since each part was in its own partial already, it was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  What is to be rendered instead?  You could potentially assert presence of this content instead.

Comment: It is possible that there is not anything to be *rendered instead*, could be a partial that simply has not to be rendered in a concrete context but the rest of the page stay same.